# How to know window href values in every 3 mins

Tags: javascript

When I go to next URL the alert didn't works. I need to get window href value every 3mins on window location onchange.

```js
var i=0;
function load(){

  var currentLoc = window.location.href;
  PrevLoc = currentLoc;
  interval(currentLoc,PrevLoc);
}

function interval(currentLoc,PrevLoc){
  setInterval(function () {

    if(currentLoc == 'https://github.com/features'){
     alert('Reached the Target Page')
    //  document.write('Reached the Target Page');
      return true;
    }

    if(currentLoc == PrevLoc){
       alert(window.location.href);
    //  document.write(window.location.href);

      if(i==0){
        PrevLoc = window.location.href;
        window.location.href = "https://github.com/join?source=login";
        currentLoc=window.location.href;
      }
      interval(currentLoc,PrevLoc);
      i++;

    }
    else {
     alert(window.location.href);
 //     document.write(window.location.href);
    }
  },3000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<body onLoad="load();">
</body>
```

I am trying this with javascript and jquery using setInterval. but it didn't work, when changed href value.

```
 <html>
 <head>


 </head>
 <body onLoad="load();">

 <script>
  function load(){
    window.location.href = "https://github.com/join?source=login"
    var PrevLoc = "https://github.com/join?source=login";
    var currentLoc = window.location.href;

    if(currentLoc == PrevLoc){
       alert('inside')
       setInterval(function () {
         alert('changed')
      },3000);
    }
   else {

   }
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: window.location.href will open the URL in the window in which the code is called.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if(currentLoc == PrevLoc){
   alert('inside')
   setInterval(function () {
     alert('changed')
  },3000);
}
```

to this or what ever you want to check:

```
setInterval(function () {
  if(currentLoc != PrevLoc){
     alert('changed')
  }
},3000);
```

Comment: i used this section on onload event.. but setTimeout function didn't call, when href value changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it will help you.

**HTML**

```
<body onload="load();">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        var PrevLoc = "https://github.com/join?source=login";
        var currentLoc = window.location.href;
        setInterval(function () {
            if(currentLoc != PrevLoc){
                alert('changed');
            }
            else {
                // Do something else...
            }
        },3000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It works first time only. then when i was changed window.href the function didn't call.  but i need to get alert even the new href value arrived.

Comment: Can you change URL of web page ?

Comment: Yes. I need to get window href on change.

Comment: Okay can you reload the page ?

Comment: Yes Jaydeep. I also tried 

window.onchange = function(){
    alert("changed");
} 

but i didn't get it. Is it Possible?

Comment: Please create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for better understanding.